# How to remove stuff inside <style> tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make this script for a forum, which allows the use of  tags in posts. Unfortunately, we can't use line breaks whenever we write these CSS styles because the form reads them as `<br>`'s and it screws everything.

They appear like this:

```
<style type="text/css"><!-- <br>#herp { background: #fff; }<br> --></style>
```

If we stop the form from reading `<br>`'s, it would affect the rest of the elements. So we've tried to remove them using this:

```
var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style"); for(x=1;x<style.length;x++) { style[x].innerHTML.replace(/\<br\>/gi,""); }
```

...to no avail.

To be honest, I'm not quite sure what kind of entities lie between these style tags. I don't think they're strings, nor are they comments. So the replace() doesn't seem to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're probably going to want to remove the `<br>`'s before the `<style>` gets added to the DOM (ie; when the form gets submitted, or changed, or on blur).

Comment: You are matching against `<br/>`, not `<br>`.

Comment: Are you submitting the CSS through a form's `<textarea>` or something? Why not simply edit the stylesheets in a more professional program and upload them? Or are you trying to allow users or mods/admins to write the stylesheets? Anyway +1 @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander: I did try to match against `<br>` but it's not working too.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, we are using `<textarea>`. Well, it's a forum of a lot of different designers and they tend to be very creative with their own posts. Plus, it's Proboards so the only thing we can do is use JS.

Comment: it seem you are trying to remove <br/> but the text contains <br>, try with /\<br\>/gi

Comment: @neu-rah Tried that already, to no avail.

Comment: May be a dumb question, how do you know the code didn't work?  I didn't see you saving the modified string to anywhere in your code?

Comment: Seeing as textareas have the `\n` character representing line breaks which is passed to the server which, when it comes to forums, usually transform `\n` in `<br>` for user inputs, you could try replacing `.replace(/\n/gi,"")` before submitting the form. *(fixed my regex)*

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Nope. Not working. :(

Comment: You have to put the function before submitting, take a look: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/4d73J/1/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Obviously doing the replacing server-side would be better than my hack above, but Proboards doesn't allow editing their phps, right?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Well my problem is, I need to disable the line breaks between style tags _only_. So like, the input ubbc code is [style], which is read as <style>. With that code, it disables the line breaks for everything (as we also use ubbc div's and td's) and it screws things up. xD

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Nope. No php edits unfortunately. :(

Comment: ohhh you have a [style] bbcode tag in your board, now that changes everything. Sorry I was mislead thinking you were submitting CSS directly through a textarea solely for them. :P

Comment: So, recapping, everything you type between `[style]` and `[/style]` gets automatically added to the document head inside a `<style type="text/css"></style>` tag, right?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté neu-rah's suggestion worked. thanks a lot though! you're the best! :D

Comment: Lol no prob, for a moment I thought it'd require a more complex function when you first said that his regex wasn't working, I'm glad you got an easy and simple solution. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var style = document.getElementsByTagName("style");
for(x=1;x<style.length;x++) {
    style[x].innerHTML=style[x].innerHTML.replace(/\<br\>/gi,"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get stylesheet object by using `document.styleSheets`

Try this in console

```
for(i in document.styleSheets){
    if(!isNaN(i)){
         document.styleSheets[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```